# Firebase Node.JS Admin SDK send verification email

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using the sdk to create a user and a db entry for the user which all works perfectly. Upon creation of the database entry I call a function to sendEmailVerification() but I am guessing this is a client side function as it returns null when being called.

What is the process to send the verify email directly from the admin sdk (if even possible). Currently what I do is send some JSON back to the client to say if the verification email sent successfully or not. But calling the function does not work so it doesn't get that far. Here is my function within node.

```
function verifiyEmail(email, res) {

    var user = admin.auth().currentUser;
    user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {


        // Email sent.
        var jsonResponse = {

            status: 'success',
            alertText: '1',
            email: email
        }

        res.send(jsonResponse); 

    }, function(error) {

        // An error happened.
        var jsonResponse = {

            status: 'success',
            alertText: '0',
            email: email
        }

        res.send(jsonResponse); 

    });

}
```

**UPDATE**

I am guessing this isn't possible so I generate a custom token in node and send that back to the client. I then use the token I get back to try and sign the user in by calling the below however the signInWithCustomToken() fuction doesnt get called. Heres my code am I missing something. Seems like a lot of work just to send out the verification email!

```
function signInUserWithToken(token) {

    firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error) {

      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;

      console.log(errorCode);
      console.log(errorMessage);

      verifiyEmail();

    });
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I scraped the token idea. All i do now is use the onAuthStateChanged() function and handle the email verification there in the client implementation. Its not perfect as this method gets called several times. However adding a flag seems to do the trick. Like the below.

```
function authListenerContractor() {
  // Listening for auth state changes.
  $('#not-verified').css('display','none'); 
  var flag = true;
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

        if (user) {

            // User is verified.
            var displayName = user.displayName;
            var email = user.email;
            var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
            var photoURL = user.photoURL;
            var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
            var uid = user.uid;
            var providerData = user.providerData;
            console.log("Email Verified?: " + emailVerified);

            if(emailVerified) {

                  window.location.href = "http://www.my-redirect-url.com";

            } else {

                if (flag == true) {

                    $('#not-verified').css('display','inherit');
                    verifiyEmail();

                    flag = false;
                }
            }

        } else {

            console.log("User is signed out.");
        }
   });
 }

function verifiyEmail() {

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {

        // Email sent.
        console.log("Verification email sent");
        $('#not-verified').text('**Email verification sent. Please check your email now!**');

    }, function(error) {

        // An error happened.
        console.log("Email verification not sent. An error has occurred! >>" + error);

    });
}
```

Comment: do you want to send the user a verification after something has been created in the firebase database ?

Comment: @RahulSingh yes thats correct.

Comment: you are using firebase cloud functions ?

Comment: @RahulSingh not sure I follow. I am using the node.js firebase admin module only.

Comment: There's an open issue in the Node.js Admin SDK requesting this feature: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/46. It might be useful to keep an eye on that ticket.

Comment: Ahhh well spotted. For now I handle it client side but yeah seems daft not to have included that in the admin sdk considering I am creating users there. I know we can set the is verified property but we need that security that the person signing in is who they say they are.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case to use `Firebase Cloud Functions`

Sending Welcome Mail Example

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const gmailEmail = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.email);
const gmailPassword = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.password);
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
    `smtps://${gmailEmail}:${gmailPassword}@smtp.gmail.com`);


const APP_NAME = 'My App';


exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {

  const user = event.data; // The Firebase user.

  const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
  const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.


  return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName);
});

function sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
    to: email
  };

  mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;
  mailOptions.text = `Hey ${displayName || ''}! Welcome to ${APP_NAME}. I hope you will enjoy our service.`;
  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    console.log('New welcome email sent to:', email);
  });
}
```

Check this [Link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/firebase) for More Info , used these functions to trigger a mail in this very app

**UPDATE**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
  `smtps://emailid:password@smtp.gmail.com`);

const APP_NAME = 'My App';

exports.sendPageCountEmail = functions.database.ref('/yournode').onWrite(event => { // here we are specifiying the node where data is created
    const data = event.data;
    return sendEmail('emailid',data);
});


// Sends a welcome email to the given user.
function sendEmail(email,body) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from:`${APP_NAME}noreply@firebase.com`,
    to: email
  };

  mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;
  mailOptions.text = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}.\n 
  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
      console.log('New welcome email sent to:', email);
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I may have a use case for this for other emails going out. But my question is simply does the admin sdk have such a function to send out the verification email like the client side does when a user signs up because calling it doesnt work and seems silly to me that this wouldnt be provided considering this is an "Admin" sdk

Comment: @AlexMcPherson when every any data is added to the firebase database at the particular node it can can send out emails too . updating with one such example

Comment: Thats great however how would I send the verification link in the email? As using the sendEmailVerification() function sends an email with the verification link in the body of the email. How do I generate that link if I were to use this method?

Comment: you can save it in the node at the time of creation and then use it when triggering this function `event.data;` in this answer. Check that link it will explain how to create such function and deploy it to firebase database

Comment: Sorry I really don't follow firebase controls the verification link as I understand it. Simply my question is this doable just with the firebase admin sdk. I don't want to send a welcome email its an actual verification link that firebase sends out.

Comment: i would suggest you to enter the verification link in the database at the time of creation of the node and then with the method created in firebase fuction access that link and then send the mail as the db will have the user details and after email sent delete the verification link if you want to

Comment: Where can I find the vertification link upon creation of the user? Or do I have to create a link myself?